# C# List overwriting

Tags: c#, list, object

I am trying to create a list of new objects that I am creating in run time for a program I am writing.

```
public class User //This is a datastructure to hold all modules as well as any other user data
{
    List<Module> moduleList = new List<Module>(); //list to contain all modules

    public void ImportAllModules() //Imports all files within the module file folder
    {
        List<List<string>> files = noteFile.getAllFiles(noteFile.moduleLoc); //Creates a jagged List of all files and contents within each file

        foreach (List<string> file in files) //For every file it creates a newmodule object
        {
            Module newModule = new Module(); //Creates new object
            newModule.PopulateModule(file); //Fully populates the object from the file
            moduleList.Add(newModule); //Adds the new module object onto the list of modules
        }
    }

}
```

I am finding that with each iteration of the foreach loop it overwrites all the previous items in the list. For example if I was trying to add 6 objects each object would be added, but then overwritten by the next object on the next loop.

The program (at this point) is loading every file within a folder into a 2d jagged list, to visualise that would be each file on the x axis then every line of text (within each file) on the y axis. Then I am running a foreach loop to extract the useful data from those files using that 2d jagged array and convert them into objects that I can use within my program. I am storing them into a list to make it easy to organise the new objects.

I have tried searching for a solution but everyone else's issue was that they were declaring the object outside of the loop, which I am not doing.

thanks for any help :)

EDIT:
here is the populate module method

```
 public void PopulateModule(List<string> file) //This will do all of the imports from a single file in one handy method
    {
        Code(ImpCode(file));
        Title(ImpTitle(file));
        Synopsis(ImpSynopsis(file));
        LearnObj(ImpLO(file));
        Assignments(ImpAssignment(file));
        Notes(ImpNote(file));
    }
```

But I presume that is not so useful for you on its own, so here are the things its actually doing for ImpCode:

```
public string ImpCode(List<string> file) //importing learning module code
    {
        try
        {
            return file[file.IndexOf("CODE") + 1];//looks for the section heading in the file, then gets the next line of the file which will have the contents and returns it.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error"); //Displays the generated error message to the user
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then the code wrapping it is just a method for setting the variable.

Comment: You have so many comments your code is unreadable.

Comment: what does pouplateModule do?

Comment: Where is `noteFile` defined?  Also are you saying you are calling `ImportAllModules` multiple times?  If so, can you show that code as well.

Comment: `"//Creates new object"` -- Really?  I mean, is that truly a necessary comment?  Is anybody going to be supporting this code who doesn't know what `new` does?  The code already says what it does, why is all of this extra text necessary?

Comment: Code as shown can't behave as described. Please make sure to provide [MCVE] for the problem.

Comment: I have edited the OP to include the info you have asked for.

Comment: @juharr
noteFile is in a separate c# file, it gets all of the files inside a folder and puts them into the 2d jagged list. I have tested that section and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason that your loop should be overwriting files. Your code looks like it should work.

As a test could you try something like the following instead of the loop :

`moduleList.AddRange(files.Select(x=>{
    Module newModule = new Module();
    newModule.PopulateModule(x);
    return newModule;
});`

And tell me what happens then?

Edit: For future visitors, the issue was that the properties of the Module class were static. This is why the values were overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: When you say "each iteration of the foreach loop" do you mean each iteration of the loop or each iteration of the call to the function that the loop is in? If the latter, are you creating a new User on each iteration?

Comment: ImportAllModules is only called once.

The foreach loop runs for every file that has been opened.

When I step through the code the following happens:

First iteration:

The foreach loop ends with the first file being converted to a object correctly.

Second iteration:

[newModule line of code] when inspecting new module it still has the same information in as the previous module from the previous iteration.

[populate line] The new module is correctly populated but all other modules in the list are now populated with the same data.

[add to list line] The new module is added to the list.

Comment: Are the properties of your Module class static?

Comment: *facepalm*, yup, that was the issue. Thank you for your help :)